# Creating folder in new HDD

Tags: 12.10, permissions, hard-drive

I just bought a brand new 2TB harddrive mainly for storage.  I formatted it as ext2.
However, I cannot create a folder inside the harddrive, nor can I move files to the harddrive

Answer (score 1):

First - formatting a large drive with ext2 was a very definite mistake.  So let's fix that.

Open `Disk Utility` from the Dash.  You will see a list of all your Storage Devices on the left.  Select the new hard drive, and click `Format Drive`.  Select the Scheme `GUID Partition Table`, and click `Format`.

[image: Partitioning]

Now, click `Create Partition` under `Volumes`.  Make sure the `Type` is set to `Ext4`, and give it a better name than `New Volume`.  Make sure `Take ownership of filesystem` is checked, and finally click `Create`.

[image: Create partition and format]

Now, click `Mount Volume` - you'll see a Mount Point of /media/`nameyoupicked`, and in the File Manager, it will show up as a mounted Device.

[image: Mounted new partition]

The new device won't automatically be mounted when you reboot, but it will still show up in File Manager and will mount automatically if you click it.

[image]

If that's not sufficient for you - if you need the disk to automatically be mounted at each boot, before you even log in - that can be done as well, but please ask it as a separate question. :)  Hope this helped!